# Call ASP.NET from javascript using image

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a page on which there is an anchor and i am calling Javascript function on anchor click. in that function i need to execute another ASP.net page. my Html Code is

```
 <a href="#tabReviews" onclick="LogReviewHits(); return false;">Reviews</a>
```

and my java script function is

```
  function LogReviewHits()
    {debugger;
        if (!reviewClickLogged){
            var img = new Image();
           img.src = "<%#RootPath%>ArrangementReviewLog.aspx" 

            reviewClickLogged = true;
         }   
        return false; 
    }
```

this code work perfectly fine in my previous application in ASP.net 3.5 but this is not calling the page in ASP.NET 4.0.
Can any one identify what I am missing.

Comment: Did you open the page directly in the browser and check? If it works, it would show you the image?

Comment: ohhh a very small mistake of mine.!!!!! and i am fed up with this since morning....